# Need help loading images using a for loop in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to load images in PyGame based on a value, like when the value is 6 it sets the image to be image number 6.

```
def bar():
    global ink
    global screen
    global barImg
    ink = 0
    for ink in range(0,100):
        barImg = pygame.image.load(f'inkbar\load{ink}.png')
        screen.blit(barImg,(100,100))
        pygame.display.update()
```

The value of ink gets changed in another function and I know that part works. Each image is called load0.png, load1.png and so on until 100, but the image never appears on the screen. I have tested putting the image on the screen by commenting out the for loop and just setting barImg to a specific image and it did put the image on the screen.

```
        px, py = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (1,0,0):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (px,py,10,10))
            
            ink+=0.5
            math.ceil(ink)
            print(ink)
```

this is part of a function that allows the user to draw. This part detects mouse click and increases the value of ink. I tried calling bar() underneath the ink increase, but that decreased the rate of drawing.

I have removed the function bar()

```
            ink+=1
            math.ceil(ink)
            print(ink)
            for ink in range(1,100):
                barImg = pygame.image.load(f'inkbar\load{ink}.png')
                screen.blit(barImg,(100,100))
```

This is what I have used as a replacement, but now ink does not increase by one, it goes from 1 to 100 immediately, and causes large amounts of lag.

Maybe the images having "load" in the name is messing with something?

Comment: Try to `print(list(range(100, 0)))`

Comment: @Tomerikoo what does that do? So far I don't see it printing anything

Comment: Exactly my point ( it ***does*** print an empty list)... Your loop doesn't run at all so no image is displayed... Did you mean `for ink in range(100)`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo for whatever reason when I set it to 100 it sets the value of ink to 100, but it's meant to start at 0.

Comment: Because there is no delay in your loop... The loop will run instantly through all numbers and only the last image will be actually displayed. Please show how you call that function with a [mre]

Comment: At the end of the code is just simply bar()

Comment: Ok, please show a [mre] of your code and explain what is your expected output

Comment: In the function is the first time barImg is defined as a variable, and the variable ink is also set to 0. For some reason though, ink is set to 100, and continues to increase when it would usually increase from 0. I call bar() at the end of the code, and when I call bar() when ink increases, that then messes up some of the other code.

Comment: Once again, it's practically impossible to help with just a function. Please read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre] so that we can help you. You should load the images as part of the main loop assuming you use a clock. Right now, your for loop just rushes through all pictures so you will only ever see the last image displayed

Comment: I don't understand why do you have a loop? If you increment `ink` and then want to update the image, why not just update it according to the new `ink`? Right now you are iterating over ***all*** images, instead of changing it once...

Comment: I removed the loop and the image works but I don't know how to make it update when ink updates

Comment: Call the function whenever you update `ink`? (Or don't use a function at all and just update `ink` and immediately after the image accordingly...)

Comment: I tried calling the function after updating ink but now when i click it spams "video system not initialised"

Comment: Did you start your code with `pygame.init()`?

Comment: yes I did. Directly under that is ink = 1

Comment: Its because i was increasing ink by 0.5 and there isnt a file called load1.5.png. It doesnt say video system initialized now but the image still doesnt change

Comment: @mkrieger1 i dont think so sorry

Comment: As explained above, `for ink in range(100, 0)` has zero iterations, so no images are loaded. This is the problem you are having, which is explained in the question I've linked.

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to how to implement this into my code. I used range(1,100), but it skipped every number between them

Comment: I think it has got to do with the ink variable declared before the for loop …..  have you tried removing it then load the images

Comment: That's because you just did `math.ceil(ink)` and didn't do nothing with it. You need to reassign the result `ink = math.ceil(ink)` or why not just increase by 1 I stead of 0.5?

Comment: And as I explained many times, your loop will simply run through all the numbers in an instant that you will not be able to see the images change. Why don't you change the image, ***once***, when `ink` changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some code for running through frames of an animation which I know works

The code:

```
frame_index += animation_speed
if frame_index >= len(animation):
  self.frame_index = 0
image = pygame.image.load(f'Ink ({int(frame_index)}).png')
screen.blit(image, (0,0))
pygame.display.update()
```

Essentially you want to have two variables, a frame index and an animation speed. The index is the number of the first image you are loading. In this case Ink 0.png or whatever it's called. So your frame index will be 0. This will increment by your animation speed variable. The higher this is, the faster your animation will be. The lower, the slower. After it loops it will go back to 0 if thats what you want. If you don't want that then you can simply remove the if statement.

Also check that you aren't filling the screen AFTER doing this as whatever you're wanting to see will just be covered instantly. Let me know if this works.

Comment: I'm not really wanting an animation. I just want for when ink = 1 it places image 1 on the screen, and when ink = 2 replaces image 1 with image 2.

Comment: This code replaces your current for loop. What you are wanting is an animation but the difference between mine and yours is that my code allows for speed to be changed so that you can choose how slow to display the images. It would be helpful if you could put your code in a github repository so I could take a look at all the code and toy with it to try and get it working

Comment: This kind of worked, a few modifications and it seems to do fine. Thanks!